# I cannot install dipy library for python, why ? In the description I explain what I did

Tags: python

I went to http://nipy.org/dipy/installation.html and install nibabel, then I when I wanted to install dipy, there where 2 problems:
`Wheel was not built`
and `vcvarshall.bat not found`.

What I did ?

- Install  Setuptools in site-pakcages
- download Setuptools-34.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (md5) and save in site-packages

I also try

```
python setup.py install --compiler=mingw32ç
```

and 
If you get an error saying `unable to find vcvarsall.bat` then you need to create a file called `pydistutils.cfg` in notepad and give it the contents

```
[build]
compiler=mingw32
```

But setup.py de system it did not find, and I still have `vcvarshall.bat not found`.

what I need to do?

I am using, Windows 7, Python 3.5.1 and Anaconda 2.5.0 (64 bit)

Comment: Do you have a c-compiler on your system, either MinGW32 or MSVC?

Comment: Well I have mingw32ccompiler.py

Comment: No, that is not the compiler. For being able to use the package, you have to install either mingw32 or msvc.

Comment: Thank you I will

Answer (score 0):

You will almost certainly find it easier to install third-party packages if you adopt virtual environments. When done correctly you will then not need admin privileges to install packages into virtualenvs. The [*HitchHikers' Guide to Python*](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) contains more information about this.

The `vcvarsall.bat` is, I believe, a part of the Visual Studio (the Express version is available at no cost) environment. It's required when you are trying to build a compiled Python extension as described in [this article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469210-Windows-Unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-cython-other-c-extensions-). I'm not sure how that will play with `mingw`.

Comment: Well, finally I installed via Anaconda, and the package actually exisits in site-packages, dipy. But when I want to import from python, it says the module does not exists

Comment: Hmm, this might be one for python-list (comp.lang.python), where there'll be people who can engage you in a dialogue to solve your problem. It sounds like the Python you are running isn't looking at the _site-packages_ where `dipy` is installed.

Answer (score 0):

So, I installed via ANACONDA but , when I go to python, and I want to import dipy it says: No modle named dipy

Comment: Ok, well that means that dipy is not a module bundled with anaconda. Anaconda is not a c++ compiler but an alternative python distribution. Try and install visual studio c++ or something.  For what its worth, installing compiled modules on windows when you're new to python / programming is painful. I found it hard, and I know others did too. Do you know how to install a compiler on your system, or what a compiler is?

Comment: Reading another post you say that dipy is in site packages. Could it be the case that just the folder is there from your previous install attempt? Where does it say that this comes bundled with Anaconda?

Comment: I have already installed Visual studio 2008 express edition, but I do not know how to continue

Answer (score 0):

Solved ! Well I had python 3.5 and dipy has some issues with that version, so I installed Anaconda with python 2.7 , installed visual c++9 and follow the steps on the web !